# SMS Telephone number confirmation with ionic and firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, sms, firebase-authentication

I am developing a mobile application with ionic and firebase. The thing I want is that for the user to be confirmed he has to enter his mobile number, receive an sms, enter the code, and then it will be confirmed.
I looked around and found some sms tools like twilio but I am not sure if I can use them. 
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at Authy?

This tutorial for account verification walks you through the setup of a Node backend for the functionality you are talking about.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/account-verification/node/express

To the best of my knowledge you should not have a problem with such a backend as ionic will handle your frontend.

Comment: I will work on it very soon. I kept this at the end of the project. I'll keep you updated @Dan

Comment: You could consider the following article: [MEAN Stack User Authentication and SMS validation with Twilio/Authy: Part 1/2 - Developing the API](https://leightley.com/mean-stack-user-authentication-and-sms-validation-with-twilio-authy-part-1-2-developing-the-api/). It migh thelp you

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';   

  let number = "+91"+ number;     
  this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
  (<any>window).FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber(number, 120, (credential) => {
    var verificationId = credential.verificationId;
    this.navCtrl.push(VerificationPage, { verificationId: verificationId, phoneNumber: this.emailPasswordForm.value["phoneNumber"]  }); //This is STEP 3 - passing verification ID to OTP Page
  }, (error) => {
    //this.eer = error;
    alert('Failed to send OTP. Try again');
    console.error(error);
  });
```

first set the sha1 to firebase setting and generate google config.json then add to poject's root directory and add to build.gradle dependency.
it'll work properly